# Ansible playbook - Run plays in parallel (and not tasks) within a playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

We have inherited quite a lot of ansible playbooks and roles/tasks underneath

One of the ansible playbook is triggered by a shell script after setting few variables

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml  install_multiple_nodes.yml
```

In the `install_multiple_nodes.yml`, it contains as following

```yaml
- hosts: all_nodes
  run_once: true
  roles:
    - set_keys
    - download_rpms
  become: true

- hosts: node1
  roles:
    - install_rpms_node1
    - custom_actions_node1
  become_user: node1_user

- hosts: node2
  roles:
    - install_rpms_node2
    - custom_actions_node2
  become_user: node2_user
  
... This continues for multiple nodes ...
```

The entire playbook takes about 1.5hours to run.
But many of the 'plays' within the playbook can be run in parallel. For instance in the above snippet, the "node1" and "node2" can be run in parallel, but later down in the chain some have to wait for another etc.

Is there a way we can

- put a flag to say the `node1` and `node2` can run in parallel?
- What's the best practice to have these type of playbooks? i.e. parallellise options and put dependency after a set of 'plays' , start next etc.

Comment: Take this a better way: rewrite the `install_rpms_nodeX, custom_actions_nodeX` roles as single ones which will accept variables you put at host/group level in your inventory to do its job correctly. Then create a single play with all nodes to be targeted and the actions will automagically play on targets in the host loop in parallel.

Comment: @Zeitounator unfortunately, the individual roles are not in our control as its owned by respective application owners. Hence I was looking to see any option to do at playbook layer.

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment, one thing you can try to work around the poor design:

```yaml
- hosts: all_nodes
  run_once: true
  roles:
    - set_keys
    - download_rpms
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Run machine specific roles
      ansible.builtin.include_role:
        name: "{{ item }}_{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      loop:
        - install_rpms
        - custom_actions
```

Notes:

- Untested, see in you own envitonment
- This will surely break as soon as there is no specific role for a given node. Add conditions/tests if this is the case.